# Error: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I've been working on some beginner php exercise recently and have encountered an error to which I have no idea what is causing it.

It says

> "Error: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'otkrica'"

The sql file is correctly named "otkrica" and my db.php looks like this:

```
<?php 
$dsn = "mysql:host=127.0.0.1;charset=utf8;dbname=otkrica";

try{

$pdo = new PDO($dsn,"root","");
  }catch(PDOException $e){
    die("Error: " . $e->getMessage());
  }
?>
```

I would really appreciate input on this one. What am I missing?

Comment: Have you actually created a database named `otkrica`?

Comment: be sure you don't have more then one mysql installation. Try to set the port you are using like:  `mysql:host=localhost;port=3307;dbname=testdb`

Comment: Yes, I did. It's in my project root folder and db.php is in root/core folder.

Comment: this is not what i said. see in your database client the port of your mysql server instalation, and set it in your 'dsn' string

Comment: That did it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer is found in the comments (credit to cmnardi). Posted as a clear answer for anyone looking:

`Set the port you are using like: mysql:host=localhost;port=3307;dbname=testdb`

Answer (score -1):

I fix this problem wait this way

```
$connect = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass);
$connect->exec("SET character_set_connection = 'utf8'");
$connect->exec("SET NAMES 'UTF8'");
```

---

```
<?php
    $server="localhost";
    $user="root";
    $pass="";
    $dbname="clicksite";
    
    $dsn="mysql:host=$server;dbname=$dbname";
    try{
    $connect=new PDO($dsn,$user,$pass);
    $connect->exec("SET character_set_connection = 'utf8'");
    $connect->exec("SET NAMES 'UTF8'");
    }catch(PDOException $error) {
    
        echo "unable to connect".$error->getMessage();
    
    }
?>
```

attention: use as wampserver ver2.5 for build database in the server
after run wampserver, click left on the icon in notify bar and then click on phpmyadmin and create the database.

Comment: Do not post images as an answer to the question.